# RestAngular vs $http on calls that aren't strictly RESTful?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Is there any point in using RestAngular if most of my calls don't end up being the usual RESTful GET all, GET by id, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc?

I understand the beauty of it for RESTful, but am I wrong in not seeing the advantage when I end up having other methods in my controllers? (E.g. returning a Dto of multiple joined tables).

Obviously the fact that you don't have to type out the full url is still there, but that's addressed by a "baseUrl" constant when using $http.

Answer (score 0):

There is some benefit in that you can inject pre and post processors for requests, but for the most part, I find your assumption correct that there is little benefit when dealing with not strictly restful endpoints.

I would also recommend that $http requests reside in services and not in your controllers.